# Is there any way to hide/show div on child component if mouse click on parent component screen?

Tags: angular

I am new to angular. I have a div that is in child component and shows/hides on the basis of a button click event:

Child:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child-component',
  templateUrl: 'child-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['child-component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})

@Input() showFilters = false;

// button click event
 openFilter() {
    this.showFilters = !this.showFilters;
  }
```

Child class HTML:

```
<div class="filterDiv" *ngIf="showFilters">
</div>
```

Parent Component:

```
<child-component> [showFilters]="showFilters" </child-component>
```

Comment: I guess your `openFilter` method should be implemented in your parent component. Please share your parent ts.

Comment: I do not have any code for openFilter in parent component.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax should be:

```
<child-component [showFilters]="showFilters"></child-component>
```

Comment: Yes it is the same, sorry i missed the closing >